# Improve runtime of the algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've written this function to return the new array with the values that are same in both the arrays. It works fine but I'm using two loops which gives the runtime of O(n^2). Any suggestions to improve the runtime of this function.

```
 var dynamicConfig = ["Test1","Test22","Test3","Test14"];
 var staticConfig = [{label: 'Test 1',value: 'Test1'},
                     {label: 'Test 2',value: 'Test2'},
                     {label: 'Test 3',value: 'Test3'}
                    ];

 function configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig) {
    var templateArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dynamicConfig.length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < staticConfig.length; j++) {
          if (dynamicConfig[i] === staticConfig[j].value) {
            templateArray.push(staticConfig[j]);
            break;
          }
        }
     }
     console.log(templateArray);
     return templateArray;
 }    
 configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig);
```

There's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zubairm/yvv2mdkr/18/) of the same.

Comment: http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-set-operations.html#intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when to find the common elements in the array,it is good practice to sort both the arrays first and then it will be easy to find the common elements.. 
but coming to javascript  you can use es6 Set function to make the task easier..

below is my code , it may appear as O(n^2) but trust me  `Set.has` is faster than 
`array.indexOf` here is the proof -> https://jsperf.com/array-indexof-vs-set-has

```
let dynamicConfig1 = ["Test1","Test22","Test3","Test14"];
let staticConfig = [
                      {
                          label: 'Test 1',
                          value: 'Test1'
                      },
                      {
                          label: 'Test 2',
                          value: 'Test2',
                      },
                      {
                          label: 'Test 3',
                          value: 'Test3',
                      }
                  ];
    let  dynamicConfig = new Set([...dynamicConfig1.map((item)=>item)])
let commonElements =  [...staticConfig].filter(x => dynamicConfig.has(x.value));
console.log(commonElements)
```

js fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/yvv2mdkr/70/

Comment: `[...dynamicConfig1.map(…)]` and `[...staticConfig]` make no sense. Drop spread syntax when you don't need it!

Comment: it is not working when you remove the spread syntax..  i dont know why

Comment: What did you try? Just `new Set(dynamicConfig1)` and `staticConfig.filter(…)` are enough!

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution with all the latest js features, much better than mine i guess :) I like it. I'm curious to know what's the runtime if it's not O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to have or convert the second 'staticConfig' array to javascript object. Javascript uses hashmap internally to implement any object. You can then get the object using map['Test 1'] which has complexity O(1). But you will have to convert the list in a separate loop for converting in an object. Overall complexity will come to O(n). Since you only need to compare value field of objects in 'staticConfig' you can also use javascript set object.
You can try something like this:

```js
var dynamicConfig = ["Test1","Test22","Test3","Test14"];
var staticConfig = [{label: 'Test 1',value: 'Test1'},
     {label: 'Test 2',value: 'Test2'},
     {label: 'Test 3',value: 'Test3'}
    ];
var map = {};
for(var i = 0; i < staticConfig.length; i++){
 var obj = staticConfig[i];
 map[obj.value] = obj.label;
}

function configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig) {
var templateArray = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < dynamicConfig.length; j++) {
   if (map[dynamicConfig[j]] != null && map[dynamicConfig[j]] != undefined && map[dynamicConfig[j]] != 'undefined') {
  templateArray.push(dynamicConfig[j]);
   }
   }
 
 console.log(templateArray);
 return templateArray;
}    
configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig);
```

Or use Set

```js
var dynamicConfig = ["Test1","Test22","Test3","Test14"];
var staticConfig = [{label: 'Test 1',value: 'Test1'},
     {label: 'Test 2',value: 'Test2'},
     {label: 'Test 3',value: 'Test3'}
    ];
var setObj = new Set();
for(var i = 0; i < staticConfig.length; i++){
 var obj = staticConfig[i];
 setObj.add(obj.value);
}

function configObj(dynamicConfig, setObj) {
var templateArray = [];
   for (var j = 0; j < dynamicConfig.length; j++) {
   if (setObj.has(dynamicConfig[j])) {
  templateArray.push(dynamicConfig[j]);
   }
   }
 
 console.log(templateArray);
 return templateArray;
}    
configObj(dynamicConfig, setObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

This below code has the time complexity of O(n). Your can also compare the 
time taken to execute for loops by calculating the start and end time.

```js
    var dynamicConfig = ["Test1","Test22","Test3","Test14"];
    var staticConfig = [{label: 'Test 1',value: 'Test1'},
                     {label: 'Test 2',value: 'Test2'},
                     {label: 'Test 3',value: 'Test3'}
                    ];

    function configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig) {
    var templateArray = [];
       for (var j = 0; j < staticConfig.length; j++) {
          if (dynamicConfig.includes(staticConfig[j].value)) {
            templateArray.push(staticConfig[j]);
          }
       }
     
     console.log(templateArray);
     return templateArray;
    }    
    configObj(dynamicConfig, staticConfig);
```